# SMTP mail not delivered

Tags: email, smtp, google-compute-engine

Filename **postfix/main.cf**

```
     # See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version
    # Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
    # line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
    # is /etc/mailname.
    #myorigin = /etc/mailname
    myorigin = mailserver.sharenodes.com
    mydomain = mailserver.sharenodes.com
    smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
    biff = no

    # appending .domain is the MUA's job.
    append_dot_mydomain = no

    # Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
    #delay_warning_time = 4h

    readme_directory = no

    # TLS parameters
    smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
    smtpd_use_tls=yes
    smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
    smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

    # See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
    # information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

    myhostname = mailserver.sharenodes.com
    alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
    alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
    mydestination = mailserver.sharenodes.com, mailserver.c.gourabpaul-1243.internal, localhost.c.gourabpaul-1243.internal, localhost
    relayhost = mailserver.sharenodes.com:2525
    mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
    mailbox_size_limit = 0
    recipient_delimiter = +
    inet_interfaces = all
    # enable SASL authentication 
    smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
    # disallow methods that allow anonymous authentication. 
    smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
    # where to find sasl_passwd
    smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
    # Enable STARTTLS encryption 
    smtp_use_tls = yes
    # where to find CA certificates
    smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

    smtp_sasl_security_options = noplaintext,noanonymous
    smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
```

Filename **postfix/master.cf**

```
2525      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
```

#
    # See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
    #
    uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
      flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
    #
    # Other external delivery methods.
    #
    ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
      flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
    bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
      flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
    scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
      flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
    mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
      flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
      ${nexthop} ${user}

```
Filename: **var/mail/root **

This is a MIME-encapsulated message.
--47F5B805CA.1458481499/mailserver.sharenodes.com
Content-Description: Notification
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
This is the mail system at host mailserver.sharenodes.com.
I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.
For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.
If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.
                   The mail system
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554 5.7.1 <gourab.p17@gmail.com>: Relay access denied
<gourab.p17@gmail.com>: host mailserver.sharenodes.com[130.211.174.34] said:
    554 5.7.1 <gourab.p17@gmail.com>: Relay access denied (in reply to RCPT TO
    command)

--47F5B805CA.1458481499/mailserver.sharenodes.com
Content-Description: Delivery report
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; mailserver.sharenodes.com
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 47F5B805CA
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; root@mailserver.sharenodes.com
Arrival-Date: Sun, 20 Mar 2016 13:44:56 +0000 (UTC)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; gourab.p17@gmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Remote-MTA: dns; mailserver.sharenodes.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554 5.7.1 <gourab.p17@gmail.com>: Relay access denied

--47F5B805CA.1458481499/mailserver.sharenodes.com
Content-Description: Undelivered Message
Content-Type: message/rfc822

Return-Path: <root@mailserver.sharenodes.com>
Received: by mailserver.sharenodes.com (Postfix, from userid 0)
        id 47F5B805CA; Sun, 20 Mar 2016 13:44:59 +0000 (UTC)
Message-Id: <20160320134459.47F5B805CA@mailserver.sharenodes.com>
Date: Sun, 20 Mar 2016 13:44:56 +0000 (UTC)
From: root@mailserver.sharenodes.com (root)

kjk
--47F5B805CA.1458481499/mailserver.sharenodes.com--
```

Not able to receive any mail by using "sendmail gourab.p17@gmail.com
test mail
."
Not able to integrate smtp with google-compute-engine.

Answer (score 0):

I think try this thing some other cloud platform.You are getting this error due google cloud security because google permanently disable the SMTP port 25.
Hope this information useful for you.